# Why isn't my Seed method called on initialization if I'm using both explicit and automatic migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 and Code First Migrations with an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. Automatic migrations are enabled but I also have several explicit migrations in the migrations folder from before I enabled automatic migrations. When I deploy to a new environment and start running/accessing the site, the explicit migrations are executed, and other automatic migrations are executed to update the database, but the `Seed()` method in my `DbMigrationsConfiguration` class is not executed. However, if I remove the explicit migrations from the Migrations folder, or if I make a change to the model, the `Seed()` method does get called, as expected. This is not really a problem since I don't need to be using a mix of explicit and implicit migrations anyway. Just has me scratching my head.